# How should I iterate over this dictionary of objects in this Django Template?

Tags: django, loops, django-templates

I have the below view.

```
def select_classes(request):
 ...
            classesBySelectedGrade = courseBlock.objects.filter(grades__grade__contains=form['grade'].value()).order_by(
                'time')
            classOptionCount = classesBySelectedGrade.all().count()    

            classOptionDict = {}    

            for i in range(classOptionCount):
                classOptionDict["option " + str(i + 1)] = classesBySelectedGrade    

    return render(request, 'select-classes.html', {'classesOptions': classOptionDict})
```

The goal of the above view:

1. Is to take a set of "courses" sorted by time.
2. Create a copy of the set of course nth many times as courses.count()
3. Add each copy to a dictionary
4. Pass this dictionary to my template.

Here is the data that is being passed.

```
 {
     'classesOptions': {
         'option 1': < QuerySet[ < courseBlock: Course Block: Some Course Block 1 - Start: 07: 00: 00, Endtime: 08: 00: 00: > , < courseBlock: Course Block: Some Course Block 2 - Start: 07: 00: 00, Endtime: 08: 00: 00: > ] > ,
         'option 2': < QuerySet[ < courseBlock: Course Block: Some Course Block 1 - Start: 07: 00: 00, Endtime: 08: 00: 00: > , < courseBlock: Course Block: Some Course Block 2 - Start: 07: 00: 00, Endtime: 08: 00: 00: > ] >
     }
 }
```

My current goal in my template:

1. To iterate over passed in dictionary to read the values out.

Here is the current loop I am using.

```
{% for classesOption in classesOptions %}

    <p>
        {{ classesOption }}

        {% for classes in classesOption %}

            {{ classes }}

        {% endfor %}

    </p>

{% endfor %}
```

And this is my output.

```
option 2 o p t i o n 2
option 1 o p t i o n 1
```

The above output is expected with the particular data I am testing.
That is I am expecting 2 copies in this test case.

For more context here are my models:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    limit = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=800)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    teachers = models.TextField(max_length=800, default="")

class startEndTime(models.Model):
    endTime = models.TimeField()
    startTime = models.TimeField()

class courseBlock(models.Model):
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='course_in_block')
    grades = models.ManyToManyField(Grade, related_name='name_in_block')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.ForeignKey(startEndTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over a dict in Python (and by extension, Django's template language) will iterate over the *keys*, not the *values*. You are then iterating over the key, which is a string. Iterating over a string will return the individual characters.

In this case it seems you want to print the key and then iterate over the value. You can use the [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method to iterate over the keys and the values at the same time:

```
{% for option, classes in classesOptions.items %}
    <p>
        {{ option }}
        {% for class in classes %}
            {{ class }}
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```